# Surjective linear map between group of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $M_n(\mathbb{R)}$ the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of $n\times n$ matrices.
Denote $O(n)$ and $S(n,\mathbb{R})$ respectively the orthogonal matrices and the symmetric matrices.
Prove that for any $X\in O(n)$ the map
$$G_X:M_n(\mathbb{R})\to S(n,\mathbb{R}), A\mapsto X^TA+A^TX$$
is surjective

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [provide context for your question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), rather than just give us the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have to prove that any symmetric matrix can be written as

$$X^TA+A^TX$$

where $X$ is a fixed orthogonal matrix of order $n$ and $A$ is any square matrix (order $n$).

Let $B$ be any symmetric matrix of order $n$, if you choose $A=\frac{1}{2}XB$, using the fact that $X^TX=Id$, it is easy to see that $G_X(A)=B$.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** It suffices to prove that the (linear!) map $F_X: M_n(\Bbb R) \to M_n(\Bbb R)$ given by
$$
A \mapsto X^TA
$$
is surjective.  That is, $F_X$ is an *invertible* linear map.